# Does anybody know the name of this View in Android?

Tags: android

i need to implement this View , but i don't know how it is called...

[image]

Comment: What is it and what does it do?

Comment: I implemented my own by using nothing more than a single **TextView**. And a **string array** to hold all the "counts" (using **Unicode** characters for filled and empty circles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not build into android, but there is a library from Jake Wharton for something similar. View Page Indicator http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about TabHost or ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

This view is to indicate the user that the focus is currently moved to another view. 
This view indicator mostly used with `ViewPager` , where you have multiple pages or fragments to display.  When the user swipe left/right on the pages, depending on the page position user will be informed that which page is shown currently.

The number of dots what you see will be equal to number of pages.

This view can be easly created, just create a small circle drawable with enabled and disabled states. Set the circle drawable  for an ImageView and add the ImageView as horizontal list view. Add the horizontal list view below or above the viewpager.

So depending on the page selected position change the horizontal item focus.